# Stop the go mod tool from parsing certain directories

Tags: go, module, go-modules

I am using a mono repo and I download certain tools under the project tree (istio). Running `go get -u` or `go mod tidy` causes the main `go.mod` to get updated with irrelevant deps.

How do I exclude certain src subpaths for consideration.

Note:

[This does not do the trick](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-an-additional-gomod-exclude-unnecessary-content-do-modules-have-the-equivalent-of-a-gitignore-file) as the subdirectories I want to exclude do have go files in them.

Comment: Directory names starting with underscore are ignored by the Go tools.

Comment: @Peter Where is that documented? I'm having a hard time finding an authoritative reference.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, "Directory and file names that begin with '.' or '_' are ignored by the go tool, as are directories named 'testdata'." https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns, last paragraph.

Comment: @peter Perfect, thanks! I thought this behavior was specific to go modules; I didn't realize it applied to the entire `go` tool.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think your two main options are:

1. A go.mod in a directory will cause that directory and all of its subdirectories to be excluded from the top-level Go module.
2. Use a leading underscore as Peter suggested, or a leading `.`.

If neither of those are appropriate, please add a comment explaining why, ideally including an error message or some other set of details about what happened when you tried.

Comment: I have a docker container and I have mapped the postgres directory to ./postgres_data and I don't want go.mod to index that directory as it is not accessible a normal user How do I do that. Currently I am using a workaround where I use an _ in the mapping but is there a way to do so